# SSRS: Oracle Data Sources Breaking After Server Updates\Restart

Tags: oracle, ssrs, ssrs-2014

Our SSRS instance has several Shared Data Sources that hit Oracle databases. Whenever we do patching or the server restarts, these Data Sources seem to break. Any reports hitting them come up with the below error message:

```
Attempt to load Oracle client libraries threw BadImageFormatException. This problem will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed.
```

This has been happening for years, and the weird part is, to fix it, the DBAs have been removing the password from the Data Source, and recopying it, and then it works fine. So it's not like something isn't installed, like the error message claims. It is almost like the server is not storing the passwords correctly. We do have several Data Sources that use SQL Server accounts, but they don't have any trouble.

Has anyone dealt with something like this before?